# Не рисует графику OpenGL(OpenTK)

Tags: c#, .net, opengl, графика, opentk

пытаюсь вывести через OpenGL фрактал Джулия, вроде бы все правильно написал, но у меня вообще ничего не рисует, уже 3 дня читаю разбираюсь. Помогите пж.

P.S. я знаю что есть юнити т.д. но лабу надо сделать на голом opengl

**Program.cs**

```
 using FractalJulia.ViewModel;

    namespace FractalJulia
    {
    internal class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            VM viewModel = new VM();
            viewModel.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

**FractalJulia.CS**

```
using FractalJulia.Models.OpenGLEngin;
using System;

namespace FractalJulia.Models.Fractals
{
    public class FractalJulia
    {
        public FractalJulia()
        {

        }

        public void DrawFractalJulia(float startX, float startY, float endX, float endY, OpenGLStart opengl)
        {
            if (opengl is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(opengl));
            }

            float cRe, cIm;
            float newRe, newIm, oldRe, oldIm;
            float zoom = 1.0f, moveX = 0f, moveY = 0f;

            int maxIterations = 300;


            cRe = -0.70176f;
            cIm = -0.3842f;

            for (float x = startX; x < endX; x += 0.001f)
            {
                for (float y = startY; y < endY; y += 0.001f)
                {
                    newRe = 1.5f * (x - endX / 2.0f) / (0.5f * zoom * endX) + moveX;
                    newIm = (y - endY / 2.0f) / (0.5f * zoom * endY) + moveY;

                    int i;

                    for (i = 0; i < maxIterations; i++)
                    {
                        oldRe = newRe;
                        oldIm = newIm;

                        newRe = oldRe * oldRe - oldIm * oldIm + cRe;
                        newIm = 2.0f * oldRe * oldIm + cIm;

                        if ((newRe * newRe + newIm * newIm) > 4) break;
                    }

                    opengl.DrawPoint(x, y, 0.2f, 0.4f, 0.22f, 1.0f);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OpenGLStart.CS**

```
using OpenTK.Windowing.Common;
using OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop;
using OpenTK.Mathematics;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
using OpenTK.Windowing.GraphicsLibraryFramework;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;

namespace FractalJulia.Models.OpenGLEngin
{
    public class OpenGLStart : GameWindow
    {
        private List<float> verticesColors;
        private float[] vertices_colors;

        private int _vertexArrayObjectId = 0;
        private ShaderProgram shaderProgram;

        public OpenGLStart(GameWindowSettings gameWindowSettings,
            NativeWindowSettings nativeWindowSettings) 
            : base(gameWindowSettings, nativeWindowSettings)
        {
            verticesColors = new List<float>();

            VSync = VSyncMode.On;
        }

        public void DrawPoint(float x, float y, float r, float g, float b, float alfa)
        {
            verticesColors.Add(x);
            verticesColors.Add(y);
            verticesColors.Add(r);
            verticesColors.Add(g);
            verticesColors.Add(b);
            verticesColors.Add(alfa);
        }
        private void ConvertListToArray()
        {
            vertices_colors = verticesColors.ToArray();
        }

        protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs args)
        {
            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);

            GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
            GL.LoadIdentity();
  
            DrawVertexArrayObjectShader();
            SwapBuffers();
            base.OnRenderFrame(args);
        }


        protected override void OnUpdateFrame(FrameEventArgs args)
        {
            var key = KeyboardState;

            if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            {
                Close();
            }

            base.OnUpdateFrame(args);
        }

        protected override void OnLoad()
        {
            ConvertListToArray();
            GL.ClearColor(Color4.Indigo);

            GL.PointSize(3.0f);


            

            shaderProgram = new ShaderProgram(@"Models\OpenGLEngin\shaders\shader_base.vert", 
                @"Models\OpenGLEngin\shaders\shader_base.frag");
            _vertexArrayObjectId = CreateVAOShaders();

            base.OnLoad();
        }

        protected override void OnUnload()
        {
            DeleteVAOShaders();
            base.OnUnload();
        }

        private void DrawVertexArrayObjectShader()
        {
            shaderProgram.ActiveProgram();
            GL.BindVertexArray(_vertexArrayObjectId);
            GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Points,0,2);
            shaderProgram.DeleteProgram();
        }

        private int CreateVBO(float[] data)
        {
            int vbo = GL.GenBuffer();
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, data.Length * sizeof(float), data, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
            return vbo;
        }

        private int CreateVAOShaders()
        {
            int vao = GL.GenVertexArray();
            GL.BindVertexArray(vao);

            int vboVC = CreateVBO(vertices_colors);

            int VertexArray = shaderProgram.GetAttribProgram("aPosition");
            int ColorArray = shaderProgram.GetAttribProgram("aColor");

            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(VertexArray);
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(ColorArray);

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vboVC);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(VertexArray, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 6 * sizeof(float), 0);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(ColorArray, 4, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 6 * sizeof(float), 2 * sizeof(float));

            GL.BindVertexArray(0);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);

            GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(VertexArray);
            GL.DisableVertexAttribArray(ColorArray);
            return vao;
        }

        private void DeleteVAOShaders()
        {
            GL.BindVertexArray(0);
            GL.DeleteVertexArray(_vertexArrayObjectId);
        }
    }
}
```

**ShaderProgram.CS**

```
using System;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4;
using OpenTK.Mathematics;
using System.IO;

namespace FractalJulia.Models.OpenGLEngin
{
    public class ShaderProgram
    {
        private readonly int _vertexShader = 0;
        private readonly int _fragmentShader = 0;
        private readonly int _program = 0;

        public ShaderProgram(string vertexfile, string fragmentfile)
        {
            _vertexShader = CreateShader(ShaderType.VertexShader, vertexfile);
            _fragmentShader = CreateShader(ShaderType.FragmentShader, fragmentfile);

            _program = GL.CreateProgram();
            GL.AttachShader(_program, _vertexShader);
            GL.AttachShader(_program, _fragmentShader);

            GL.LinkProgram(_program);
            GL.GetProgram(_program, GetProgramParameterName.LinkStatus, out var code);
            if (code != (int)All.True)
            {
                var infoLog = GL.GetProgramInfoLog(_program);
                throw new Exception($"Ошибка линковки шейдерной программы № {_program} \n\n {infoLog}");
            }

            DeleteShader(_vertexShader);
            DeleteShader(_fragmentShader);
        }

        public void ActiveProgram() => GL.UseProgram(_program);

        public void DeactiveProgram() => GL.UseProgram(0);

        public void DeleteProgram() => GL.DeleteProgram(_program);

        public int GetAttribProgram(string name) => GL.GetAttribLocation(_program, name);

        public void SetUniform4(string name, Vector4 vec)
        {
            int location = GL.GetUniformLocation(_program, name);
            GL.Uniform4(location, vec);
        }

        private int CreateShader(ShaderType shaderType, string shaderFile)
        {
            string shaderStr = File.ReadAllText(shaderFile);
            int shaderID = GL.CreateShader(shaderType);
            GL.ShaderSource(shaderID, shaderStr);
            GL.CompileShader(shaderID);

            GL.GetShader(shaderID, ShaderParameter.CompileStatus, out var code);
            if (code != (int)All.True)
            {
                var infoLog = GL.GetShaderInfoLog(shaderID);
                throw new Exception($"Ошибка прикомпиляции шейдера № {shaderID} \n\n {infoLog}");
            }

            return shaderID;
        }

        private void DeleteShader(int shader)
        {
            GL.DetachShader(_program, shader);
            GL.DeleteShader(shader);
        }

    }
}
```

**VM.cs**

```
using FractalJulia.Models.OpenGLEngin;
using System;
using OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop;
using OpenTK.Mathematics;
using OpenTK.Windowing.Common;

namespace FractalJulia.ViewModel
{
    public class VM
    {
        private OpenGLStart openGL;
        private Models.Fractals.FractalJulia fractal;
        private NativeWindowSettings nativeWinSettings;
        public VM()
        {
            nativeWinSettings = new NativeWindowSettings()
            {
                Size = new Vector2i(800, 600),
                Location = new Vector2i(370, 300),
                WindowBorder = WindowBorder.Resizable,
                WindowState = WindowState.Normal,


                // Flags = ContextFlags.ForwardCompatible,
                Flags = ContextFlags.Default,
                APIVersion = new Version(3, 3),
                Profile = ContextProfile.Compatability,
                // Profile = ContextProfile.Core,
                API = ContextAPI.OpenGL,
            };

            openGL = new OpenGLStart(GameWindowSettings.Default,
                nativeWinSettings);
            fractal = new Models.Fractals.FractalJulia();
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            fractal.DrawFractalJulia(-1.0f, -1.2f, 1.0f, 1.2f, openGL);

            openGL.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

**shader_base.vert**

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 aPosition;
in vec4 aColor;

out vec4 inColorFraf;

uniform vec4 color;

void main()
{
    
    inColorFraf = aColor;
    gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 1.0);
}
```

**shader_base.frag**

```
#version 330 core

in vec4 inColorFraf;

out vec4 outColor;


void main()
{
    outColor = inColorFraf;
}
```

Comment: Если надо сделать на "голом OpenGL", может GLSL лучше подойдёт? https://www.shadertoy.com/view/3llyzl

Comment: ну не на совсем на голом) а именно на c# + opengl(opentk)

Comment: Про opentk не подскажу, но может попробовать bitmap собирать как [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/articles/206516/), чтобы убедиться, что работает?

Comment: Посмотрел по битмапу, чтобы нарисовать через неё там координаты надо в int а у меня они во float. если я ошибаюсь можно пожалуйста ссылку на статью где можно посмотреть

Comment: Так ссылка на habr выше, там код под треугольником.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже ответил здесь
http://programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=346033
Вкратце, ошибка в неверном параметре количества записей для рисовки из массива. Нужно исправить вот так:
`GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Points,0,vertices_colors.Length);`
Также нужно поправить расчет цвета, сейчас все зеленое из-за констант:
`opengl.DrawPoint(x, y, 0.2f, 0.4f, 0.22f, 1.0f);`